# Trailing slash when Tab auto complete in Windows 7 PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, slash

I couldn't find any answer in Google search how to add a trailing slash "/" at the end of auto completion when Tab key is pressed in Windows 7 PowerShell. On my Ubuntu the slash is at the end whenever you press Tab key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you give [PSReadline](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) a try as it will do this during auto-complete along with much, much more.  I've written up a [blog post on PSReadline's capabilities](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/psreadline-a-better-line-editing-experience-for-the-powershell-console/). I highly recommend PSReadline.

Comment: Great. Works exactly as needed. Thank you for quick response